# Redux-saga and Typescript error : Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: typescript, redux-saga

The code below in my store configuration generates the following error when I declare the createSagaMiddleware() function :

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof import("/myProject/node_modules/redux-saga/index")' has no compatible call signatures
```

I am not sure what that means. There is little detail in the redux-saga package and in the redux-saga doc.

```
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

export default function configureStore(preloadedState: any) {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    preloadedState,
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, loggerMiddleware)
  )
}
```

Comment: Please add your import statement, that is where the problem is (at least that is my suspicion)

Comment: Apparently my hunch was wrong .. you code should work (i tried the code in the assnwer I deleted and it worked with the latest npm packpage.) What is your tsconfig what package versions do you have ?

Comment: I use the default typescript config that comes with CRA. I haven't edited the tsconfig file. The problem may have to do with the tsconfig as you suggest indeed.